# Is there a function for aborting routing calculation in optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to have a function like if the calculation time get too long,  we abort routing calculation and submit the best solution at the point of time. Is there such a function in optaplanner ?

Answer (score 2):

For example in a GUI application, you would start solving on a background (worker) thread. In this scenario you can stop solver asynchronously by calling `solver.terminateEarly()` from another thread, typically the UI thread when you click a stop button.

If this is not what you're looking for, read on.

Provided that by calculation you actually mean the time spent solving, you have several options how to stop solver. Besides asynchronous termination described in the first paragraph, you can use synchronous termination:

1. Use **time spent** termination if you know how much time you want dedicate to solving beforehand.
2. Use **unimproved time spent** termination if you want to stop solving if the solution doesn't improve for a specified amount of time.
3. Use **best score** termination if you want to stop solving after a certain score has been reached.

Synchronous termination is defined before starting the solver and it's done either by XML solver configuration or using the `SolverConfig` API. See [OptaPlanner documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#termination) for other termination conditions.

Lastly, in case you're talking about **score calculation** and it takes too long to calculate score for a single move (solution change) then you're most certainly doing something wrong. For OptaPlanner to be able to search the solution space effectively, the **score calculation must be fast** (at least 1000 calculations per second).

For example in vehicle routing problem, driving time or road distances must be known at the time when you start solving. You shouldn't slow down score calculation with a heavy computation that can be done beforehand.